# multistage random sampling in r not based on rows, but based on group and unique values in another column

Tags: r, for-loop, random, nested-loops

I want to carry out multistage random sampling on a master [dataframe](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ym_s5KeqcQ9yZFBK2nO6FGhC_WYVUv8x/view?usp=sharing), in order to compare results of different sample sizes. Different examples that I have seen on stackoverflow have carried out sampling based on number of rows, but that is not exactly the expectation in this task. Overview of the master dataframe is this:

```
glimpse(df)
Rows: 23,404
Columns: 4
$ variety <dbl> 330, 330, 330, 330, 330, 330, 251, 251, 251, 251, 251, 251, 312, 312, 312, 312, 312, 312, 312, 31...
$ plantno <dbl> 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 29, 29, 29, 29, 2...
$ point   <chr> "L.0000", "L.0001", "R.0000", "R.0001", "R.0002", "R.0003", "L.0000", "L.0001", "L.0002", "R.0000...
$ length  <dbl> 31.9868410, 25.7816640, 18.4944923, 19.5613560, 10.7766413, 10.1496060, 10.7168411, 8.5189431, 10...
```

The sampling are done in two stages:

- 1st stage - sample plants per variety (this is not equivalent to rows). Sample sizes are `5 10 15 20 25 30 35`. For instance, sampling `5` plants per variety will not mean sampling five rows but sampling unique five `plantno`, which in real sense goes along with their replicates. The picture below shows a correct example of sampling after stage 1. It shows that under variety 201, five plants `15 10  18 17 36` from  `plantno` column were sampled.

[image: example of sampling after stage 1]

- 2nd stage - sample `point` per `plantno`. Sample sizes are `2  4  6  8 10`. The picture below shows a correct example of sampling after stage 2. For example, sampling `2` points per `plantno` shows that under `variety` 201, `plantno` 10 & 15 were sampled from the 1st stage, while for the 2nd stage, `L.0002` & `R.0004` were sampled from `plantno` 10, and `L.0002` sampled from  `plantno` 15. Stage 2 is actually the final result. Each sampling cycle is stored in a list which are later joined together.

[image: example of sampling after stage 2]

The attempt I made according to the code below did not give me expected result. The result seem to be filled with duplicates, and not according to the table shown above. The . Any help will be appreciated.

```
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
library(rio)
library(tidyverse)

# import data from the web to your local computer
myurl <- "https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ym_s5KeqcQ9yZFBK2nO6FGhC_WYVUv8x/view?usp=sharing"
download.file(url=myurl, destfile="df_test1.xlsx", mode="wb")

# import multiple excel workbook using rio library
df <- import_list(file.choose(), setclass = "tbl")
df <- df[[1]]
glimpse(df)

## generate sequence of sample sizes for tree per family
J <- seq(5,35,5)
# l1 <- vector(length = length(J), mode = "list")

## generate sequence of points per tree
k <- seq(2,10,2)
l2 <- vector(length = length(k), mode = "list")
l3 <- vector(length = length(J), mode = "list")

for (i in seq_along(J)){    # you know of seq_along() right?
  l1 = df %>%
    group_by(plantno, variety) %>%
    # distinct %>%
    sample_n(J[i], replace = T)
  # 
  # l1 <- l1 %>% left_join(df)
  
  sampleSize_variety <- rep(J[i], nrow(l1))
  
  l1$sampleSize_variety <- sampleSize_variety
  
  for (j in seq_along(k)){  
    l4 = l1 %>%
      group_by(variety, plantno) %>% 
      sample_n(k[j], replace = T) 
    
    sampleSize_pointPerPlant <- rep(k[j], nrow(l4))
    
    l4$sampleSize_pointPerPlant <- sampleSize_pointPerPlant
    
    l2[[j]] = l4
  }
  l3[[i]] <- l2
}

# bind tables together - tables are in nested list
merge_table <-  transpose(l3) %>% map(bind_rows) 
merge_table1 <- bind_rows(merge_table)
merge_table1
```

Comment: Ref-Stage-1 sampling? what do different sample sizes for each variety mean? Similarly for stage-2? e.g. under variety 201 5 plants were sampled, but what do other sizes i.e. 10, 15, 20, 25, 30 and 35 mean in this case?

Comment: Thanks @AnilGoyal. There are about 144 unique varieties. So for Stage 1, `plantno` is sampled (with replacement) within each variety using following  sample sizes `5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35`. Sample sizes does not mean number of rows but number of unique `plantno`. For instance, if  `10` is sampled within a variety, it means all `plantno` `10` within that variety is automatically sampled. Each sampling produces a table that is passed to stage 2. For stage 2, sampling is carried out on `point` within already sampled `plantno`. The sample sizes at this stage are `2,  4, 6,  8, 10`.

Comment: The methodology i understood, but i am not getting the different sizes of probabilities.  Your sample sizes are 7*5.  Do you want 35 different samples?

Comment: Hi @AnilGoyal, you are correct. In total, 35 different sampling (7 X 5) with replacement. The result of each sampling is a dataframe, and at the end, all the 35 dataframes will be `bind_row` together. I used this lines of code to do that:    
`merge_table <-  transpose(l3) %>% map(bind_rows); `
`merge_table1 <- bind_rows(merge_table);`
`merge_table1 `

Comment: If you will `rbind` all 35 results, there will be lots and lots of duplicate records!  See in two different samples some members can be same, so what purpose will it serve to combine all results?